# Temporal aggregation in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, spatial, aggregation, temporal

I have a database of climatic data for farms in postgresql/postgis. it contains information about temperature, humidity and ... for farms and it is updated every hour. I need to perform some (spatio-)temporal aggregation on it. the queries would be like "for every square kilometer of the country, compute the monthly precipitation". I was wondering if there are some functions to do that or I should write the desired algorithm for it.

Thank you

Comment: The question is too abstract. Firstly show us your DB tables' structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a regular grid that covers the entire country e.g. with 1 kilometer square length.

Such grid can be generated using QGIS or write a function in PostgreSQL. Save your grid in a separate table (every cell is a polygon), then you can join the grid table and your data table group by grid cell and time to do your aggregation